# Django lte/gte query on a list

Tags: python, django, performance, list, filter

I have the following type of data:

The data is segmented into "frames" and each frame has a start and stop "gpstime". Within each frame are a bunch of points with a "gpstime" value.

There is a frames model that has a frame_name,start_gps,stop_gps,...

Let's say I have a list of gpstime values and want to find the corresponding frame_name for each.

I could just do a loop...

```
framenames = [frames.objects.filter(start_gps__lte=gpstime[idx],stop_gps__gte=gpstime[idx]).values_list('frame_name',flat=True) for idx in range(len(gpstime))]
```

This will give me a list of 'frame_name', one for each gpstime. This is what I want. However this is very slow.

What I want to know: Is there a better way to preform this lookup to get a framename for each gpstime that is more efficient than iterating over the list. This list could get faily large.

Thanks!

**EDIT: Frames model**

```
class frames(models.Model):
    frame_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    frame_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    start_gps = models.FloatField()
    stop_gps = models.FloatField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s"%(self.frame_name)
```

Comment: Can you include the model code for the `frames` model? Also, you say the list could get fairly large - how large exactly?

Comment: Frames added, the list could get into the 10K + range thought most of the time it will be around 1-5K elements.

Comment: Well, you should be able to get a speed improvement by adding an index on `start_gps` with `start_gps = models.FloatField(db_index=True)`. For an existing table, you'll have to add the index via SQL.

Comment: However, this still may not be good enough. A couple of other questions: a) how many rows are in the `frames` table? b) is there any obvious pattern to the `start_gps` and `stop_gps` values? If you could provide a very small sample of data from the `frames` table, it would be easier to see if there's some way to re-index the data to make it faster.

Comment: The frames table is very large, but I have another value that lowers the frames searched in this case to under 50. There is not really a pattern, each frame starts at the same gpstime the previous stops. The frames table has each row : FRAME_ID,FRAME_NAME,GPSSTART,GPSSTOP, for example 1,'20110509_01_001',float,float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, gpstime is a list of the times, and you want to produce a list of framenames with one for each gpstime. Your current way of doing this is indeed very slow because it makes a db query for each timestamp. You need to minimize the number of db hits.

The answer that comes first to my head uses numpy. Note that I'm not making any extra assumptions here. If your gpstime list can be sorted, i.e. the ordering does not matter, then it could be done much faster.

Try something like this:

```
from numpy import array
frame_start_times=array(Frame.objects.all().values_list('start_time'))
frame_end_times=array(Frame.objects.all().values_list('end_time'))
frame_names=array(Frame.objects.all().values_list('frame_name'))
frame_names_for_times=[]
for time in gpstime:
    frame_inds=frame_start_times[(frame_start_times<time) & (frame_end_times>time)]
    frame_names_for_times.append(frame_names[frame_inds].tostring())
```

EDIT:
Since the list is sorted, you can use `.searchsorted()`:

```
from numpy import array as a
gpstimes=a([151,152,153,190,649,652,920,996])
starts=a([100,600,900,1000])
ends=a([180,650,950,1000])
names=a(['a','b','c','d',])
names_for_times=[]

for time in gpstimes:
    start_pos=starts.searchsorted(time)
    end_pos=ends.searchsorted(time)
    if start_pos-1 == end_pos:
        print time, names[end_pos]
    else:
        print str(time) + ' was not within any frame'
```

Comment: The gpstime list is already sorted. How could this be improved making this additional assumption? Thanks!

Comment: Have edited my answer to use numpy's searchsorted() . Brent's answer below has a good point that if you do have to do lots of database calls, you should index your fields. However, doing the work in memory instead of on the disk (the db) should be much faster.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to speed things up is to add indexes to those fields:

```
start_gps = models.FloatField(db_index=True)
stop_gps = models.FloatField(db_index=True)
```

and then run `manage.py dbsync`.

Answer (score 0):

> The frames table is very large, but I have another value that lowers
>   the frames searched in this case to under 50. There is not really a
>   pattern, each frame starts at the same gpstime the previous stops.

I don't quite understand how you lowered the number of searched frames to 50, but if you're searching for, say, 10,000 `gpstime` values in only 50 `frames`, then it's probably easiest to load those 50 frames into RAM, and do the search in Python, using something similar to foobarbecue's answer.

However, if you're searching for, say, 10 `gpstime` values in the entire table which has, say, 10,000,000 `frames`, then you may not want to load all 10,000,000 frames into RAM.

You can get the DB to do something similar by adding the following index...

```
ALTER TABLE myapp_frames ADD UNIQUE KEY my_key (start_gps, stop_gps, frame_name);
```

...then using a query like this...

```
(SELECT frame_name FROM myapp_frames
        WHERE 2.5 BETWEEN start_gps AND stop_gps LIMIT 1)
    UNION ALL
(SELECT frame_name FROM myapp_frames
        WHERE 4.5 BETWEEN start_gps AND stop_gps LIMIT 1) 
    UNION ALL
(SELECT frame_name FROM myapp_frames
        WHERE 7.5 BETWEEN start_gps AND stop_gps LIMIT 1);
```

...which returns...

```
+------------+
| frame_name |
+------------+
| Frame 2    |
| Frame 4    |
| Frame 7    |
+------------+
```

...and for which an `EXPLAIN` shows...

```
+----+--------------+--------------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type  | table        | type  | possible_keys | key    | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                    |
+----+--------------+--------------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY      | myapp_frames | range | my_key        | my_key | 8       | NULL |    3 | Using where; Using index |
|  2 | UNION        | myapp_frames | range | my_key        | my_key | 8       | NULL |    5 | Using where; Using index |
|  3 | UNION        | myapp_frames | range | my_key        | my_key | 8       | NULL |    8 | Using where; Using index |
| NULL | UNION RESULT | <union1,2,3> | ALL   | NULL          | NULL   | NULL    | NULL | NULL |                          |
+----+--------------+--------------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
```

...so you can do all the lookups in one query which hits that index, and the index should be cached in RAM.